# Crop is not working for this image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, crop

i need to crop the below image by detecting co-ordinates of the image using opencv.
i tried below code but it's not working as expected.

```
import cv2

#reading image
image = cv2.imread("input.PNG")

#converting to gray scale
gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#applying canny edge detection
edged = cv2.Canny(image, 10, 250)

#finding contours
(_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
idx = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if w>50 and h>50:
        idx+=1
        new_img=image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        #cropping images
        cv2.imwrite("cropped/"+str(idx) + '.png', new_img)
#cv2.imshow("Original Image",image)
#cv2.imshow("Canny Edge",edged)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Input Image:

[image]

Output image:

[image]

Comment: What you are looking for is `cv2.minAreaRect()`

Comment: uploaded  input and expected output image. Please check

Comment: Watching the input and output images you would not only to crop the image but to rotate them, isn't it?

Comment: No,its already orientation is done.need to crop only

Comment: @DavidSerrano ,sorry yes you are right. after crop again rotate is needed.

Comment: This doesn't do anything if you put inside if/else block condition new_img=image[y:y+h,x:x+w]. This could be outside of if/else block condition. Otherwise, remove it if/else condition. I haven't tested it. Btw,  replace this (_, cnts, _) to (cnts, _).

Answer (score 1):

Cropping the image based on coordinates returned from `cv2.boundingRect()` will not give you the desired result. You need to obtain the 4 corners of the image and orient it accordingly. This can be done using the perspective transformation matrix

Also, detecting edges and later finding contours is not the right way to go. You need to find a contour large enough to enclose the entire page. To do so, binarize the image and find the largest external contour.

**Code:**

```
# read image and binarize
img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\524316\Desktop\Stack\dc.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# find the largest contour
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)

# To find the 4 corners of the contour
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
input_corners = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
input_corners = np.int0(input_corners)

# We need 4 new points onto which the 4 input points need to be warped
# which will be done on an image with the same size as the input image
ht, wd = img.shape[:2]
output_corners = [[0,0], [wd,0], [wd,ht], [0,ht]]

# converting to float data type
input_corners = np.float32(input_corners)
output_corners = np.float32(output_corners)

# get the transformation matrix
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(input_corners, output_corners)
# perform warping 
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (wd, ht))

cv2.imshow('Warped output', warped)
```

**Result:**

[image]